# Does any body know how to make a VPN connection programmatically using L2TP/IPSec server protocol in android?

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn, background-service, l2tp

Does any body know how to make a VPN connection programmatically using L2TP/IPSec server protocol in android?

I'm trying to connect to my VPN server with L2TP/IPSec protocol through my android application, as i was researching I found out that with android.net.vpnservice I could connect, but as I read some of documentation it was not clear how to connect to VPN (there were no API to set username or password, and also no API to set my VPN type(l2tp,pptp); I also tested example application Google provided(toyvpn) and there were none of what I mentioned earlier there too.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: i have tried using toyvpn but only able to see sent packets but not receive. im still looking for answers too. maybe you can do it

Comment: I'm making an app similar to this. Have you ever figured out a way to do this?

Comment: @BkRazor did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

VPN Service is just a framework that Google provides you to let you make your own VPN solution, so if you want to use L2TP/IPSec maybe you should just extends the VPNService and make ur own implementation about that

Comment: I'm making an app similar to this. Have you ever figured out a way to do this?